# Asp.net core razor pages,identity, external login returns error Correlation failed

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I have a website set up and running, and when going through my logs I found the error posted below.  I have found similar issues, but they were all using odic and not Identity.

I tested locally and the same issue appears.

I have https and www redirection set up, so tried to disable those and still got the same result.

I tried moving app.UseAuthentication(); around, which did no good either.

I have the add trailing slash option enabled, disabling that had no effect...

I'm stumped.

> Exception
>   System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

As seen with the odic issues I read up on, refreshing the page will allow the process to continue.
 my ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
            options.MimeTypes =
                ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "image/svg+xml" });
        });
        services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
        });
        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString")));
        services.AddDbContext<LoggingDbContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString"));
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddAuthentication()
                        .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
                        {
                            microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                            microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                        })
                        .AddGoogle(options =>
                        {
                            IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                                Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                            options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                            options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                        })
                        .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => {
                            facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                            facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                        });
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        });
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        });

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });
        services.AddSession();
        //services.AddResponseCaching();
        var adminPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                      .RequireRole(Administrator)
                      .Build();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy => {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole(Administrator);
            });
        });
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Users");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/ViewProfile");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/NewsFeed");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/PostEdit");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/PostDelete");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Message");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/RelationshipManager");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Administration", "/", "RequireAdmin");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Privacy");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Terms");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToAreaPage("Horses", "/HorseBrowser/Index");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Horses", "/HorseBrowser/AddHorse");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Horses", "/HorseBrowser/EditHorse");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Horses", "/HorseBrowser/DeleteHorse");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Horses", "/MakeAnOffer");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Horses", "/Oops");

        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        .AddJsonOptions(x => {
            x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            x.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        }).AddFacebookWebHooks();
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        });
        services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
        services.Configure<MailGunSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailGunSettings"));
        services.Configure<FacebookOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(FacebookOptions)));
        services.AddSingleton<IUploadSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("UploadSettings").Get<UploadSettings>());
        services.AddSingleton<IVapidKeys>(Configuration.GetSection("VapidKeys").Get<VapidKeys>());

        services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddHttpClient<CountriesService>();
        services.AddAngleSharp();
        services.AddSingleton<GenericPageScraper>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, EmailBasedUserIdProvider>();
        services.AddScoped<IChatRepository, ChatRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPostRepository, PostRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IHorseRepository, HorseRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IWebPushRepository, WebPushRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ILogsRepository, LogsRepository>();

    }
```

And my Congure:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseAspNetCoreExceptionHandler();
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
        .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent();
        app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSignalR(hubs =>
        {
            hubs.MapHub<NagbookHub>("/hub");
            hubs.MapHub<PostHub>("/posthub");
        });
        app.UseSession();
        //app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

The error is with any provider be it Microsoft, Facebook or Google.

I am using inprocess and hosting is on IIS within a VPS running server 2012R2.

Any help with this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so face palm time...

All I had to do is change the cookie policy to:

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        });
```

Pretty obvious really, and always right there at the top of the code... urgh.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking you callback url and return url.I fixed this error by changing return url.